# Code Contract's properties in Visual Studio 2010 Pro RC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-contracts

So it seems there should be a "Code Contracts" tab in Visual Studio 2010's properties. I can't find it anywhere. Maybe it's a problem with my Visual Studio installation? I am running the RC version.

This is what I have:

[alt text http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/5928/lcmitpm2aur5e4uiabdtofw.png](http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/5928/lcmitpm2aur5e4uiabdtofw.png)

Anyone knows what might be wrong? Maybe I am looking in the wrong place?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to download and install [code contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx) first. Even then, you'll only get run-time checking of contracts. Static checking requires the premium edition of visual studio.

Comment: BTW, I have put in a request to get Code Contracts support in all editions of Visual Studio (http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2268646-include-code-contracts-features-in-all-editions-of). Some votes may help.

Answer (score 3):

Have you actually installed the [Code Contracts stuff from DevLabs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx)?

Comment: Ah, I assumed it came with VS 2010? It even has the System.Diagnostics.Contracts namespace and so loaded into VS.

Comment: My understanding is that although `System.Diagnostics.Contracts` is included in .NET 4 you also need the separate install to get the tools and the VS integration.